# ~5 секунд задержки при получении ответа из Mysql на PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Всем доброго времени! Уже который день бьюсь с такой проблемой:
Для начала поясню : моя программа работает уже довольно давно - лет 8. Несколько раз слетал сервер, падала база: всегда удавалось восстановить работоспособность системы. Последний раз произошел очередной сбой (по питанию), с потерями данных. Работоспособность программы удалось быстро восстановить на новом железе. Всё работает, но появилась странная задержка в районе 5 секунд при получении ответа от БД Mysql. Рою третий день - результата пока нисколько не имею.

```
$start = getMicrotime();

$sql ='SELECT v.Id, v.rrec, v.dpos, v.fio, v.age, v.ndoc, v.adr, v.ncard, v.wrk, v.Doc, v.ukus, v.dopl, v.typ, v.ctz FROM hospb.visits v WHERE (v.ctz LIKE "'.$ctz.'")&(v.dpos LIKE "'.$f_datp.'%")& (v.clin = "'.$podr.'")&  ((v.fio LIKE "%'.$f_text.'%")| (v.adr LIKE "%'.$f_text.'%")| (v.wrk LIKE "%'.$f_text.'%")| (v.ndoc LIKE "%'.$f_text.'%")) ORDER BY v.dpos DESC';

$result = sndbd($sql);

printf('Время работы скрипта  %.4F сек.', getMicrotime()-$start);

...
function sndbd($sql)
{
global $mysqli;
$result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
return $result;
}        

function getMicrotime() { return microtime(true);}
```

Так мерю время обработки.

[image: отладчик хрома]

Но самое странное что при запросе данных через jScript (так же к страничке PHP) - все работает идеально! (методом  xmlhttp.open)

Если кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите куда копать плз!

Windows 10, Apache 2.4.27, PHP 5.2.0, Mysql 5.7

Comment: вы в браузере замеряете время работы скриптов на сервере?

Comment: А что выдает `printf` из кода?

Comment: Print _f выдает 5 секунд( +-) Вобщем вопрос решен странным способом: Удалил часть базы данных, которая не используется (копия старых записей, на всякий случай) и всё заработало как положено.  Одно странно - я не обращался к этим записям: как они моли повлиять на скорость обработки запроса?